# Why is my code jumping out of a loop In php

Tags: php, mysqli, simple-html-dom

I am writing a project on web scraping using simple HTML DOM parser. I scrape web pages from my database, extract contents and store then in database. The code is working fine with the first URL, but on the remaining URL it just break out of the loop. Below is my code.

```
include_once('Connections/elecom_connect.php');
include_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php');

mysqli_select_db($elecom_connect,$database_elecom_connect);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM link_data";
$result_links = array();
$result_cates = '';
$result_subs = '';
$result_names = '';
$num = -1;
$count = 0;

$img = '.image-wrapper img';
$brand = 'h2.title span.brand';
$name = 'h2.title span.name';
$price = 'span.price-box';
$link = 'section.products a.link';

$site = new simple_html_dom();

$query = mysqli_query($elecom_connect,$sql);

if (!$query){
    echo 'Database error: ' .    mysqli_error($elecom_connect);
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $result_links[] =  $row;
}

foreach($result_links as $link){
    $var = $link['link'];
    if (!empty($var)) {
        var_dump($var);

        $site->load_file($var);
        if (!empty($site)) {
            $currentImg = $site->find($img);
            $currentBrand = $site->find($brand);
            $currentName = $site->find($name);
            $currentPrice = $site->find($price);
            $currentLink = $site->find($link);

            $rid = $link['id'];
            $rcates = $link['link_category'];
            $rsubs = $link['link_subcategory'];
            $rnames = $link['link_name'];
            if (!empty($currentImg)) {
                foreach($currentImg as $im){
                    $count++;

                    if($count % 2 == 0 && $count < 40){
                        $num++;

                        $cImg = $im->src;
                        $cBrand = "<p>".$currentBrand[$num]->plaintext."</p>";
                        $cName = "<p>".$currentName[$num]->plaintext."</p>";
                        $cPrice = "<p>".$currentPrice[$num]->plaintext."</p>";
                        //$cLink = $currentLink[$num]->href;

                        $content = file_get_contents($cImg);
                        //Store in the filesystem.
                        $save_path = "cachedPages/$rid.$num.jpg";
                        file_put_contents($save_path,$content);

                        $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO item_detail (item_name, item_brand, item_price, item_img, item_cate, item_sub_cate,filter_by) VALUES ('$cName', '$cBrand', '$cPrice','$save_path','$rcates','$rsubs','$rnames')";

                        mysqli_select_db($elecom_connect,$database_elecom_connect);
                        $Result1 = mysqli_query($elecom_connect,$insertSQL) or die(mysqli_error(          $elecom_connect));

                        echo 'Success';


                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    $site->clear();
}
```

Here is the error code I get.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on null in dom/simple_html_dom.php:1113 Stack trace: #0

What should I do.?

Comment: Make sure that your $image $brand $price $link and $name is not set to null in dom/simple_html_dom.php file

Comment: They are not set to null. It ran the first time with the first URL, but couldn't run again with the second URL

Comment: I cannot get it to reproduce with empty check but that error is saying `$site` is `null` and `null` does not have a `find()` method. How it is getting past empty IDK. Is this `simple_html_dom` file?

Comment: @nerdlyist yes it's a simple_html_dom parser..

Comment: What line here is number `1113`? The error is pretty obvious as to what the issue is. Given the code above, it wouldn't throw that error as the only call to `find` is from `$site` and you are checking if `!empty($site)`. So I would assume that this isn't the whole file (obviously it isn't as I don't see 1100 lines of code) and the error is somewhere else in your code or you haven't saved your file in a while and the code you are running is out of date.

Comment: The simple_html_dom.php is a class file. And line 1113 contains this function:                               function find($selector, $idx=null, $lowercase=false) { return $this->root->find(selector, $idx, $lowercase);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code is incorrect:

```
$site = new simple_html_dom();
```

You apparently do not need to do this based on the example directory in GitHub https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom/tree/master/example

What you want to do is use one of two methods

`file_get_html` or `str_get_html` which are loaded when you include the `include_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php');`.

So you actually want to see

```
$site = file_get_html($url); //URL to a site you are parsing ie 'http://www.google.com/'
//OR 
$site = str_get_html($str); // String file to some html file
```

Which if you read the code actually creates a `$dom_node` which has the `find` method on it.

The reason what you have is strange is because you are creating and object and when you check `if(!empty($site))` it returns true because there is an object. However that internal `dom_node` is not set properly.

When you get to line 1113 of this libs file not yours you have a null `dom_node` which `null->find()` will throw the error you are getting.

Comment: please I will upvote as soon as I get hold of my laptop and try out the given answer.

Comment: Here is the new error msg I had after working with ur suggestions 
Warning: file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking in dom/simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to seek to position -1 in the stream in dom/simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Comment: @RoseMba Can you `var_dump($cImg)`? I am not sure what is in that var but based on the error it is a `dom` object and not a file path.

Comment: The script did not execute to that point (var_dump($cImg)). From the simple_html_dom  change_log.txt I saw this update:                           [On going]
1. Error of "file_get_contents()" will be thrown as an exception.
2. Add flag: LOCK_EX while calling "file_put_contents()". 
3. Fix the typo of "token_blank_t".

Comment: I checked  `var_dump($site)`  and it shows `boolean(false)`  ....Please what should I do?

Comment: @RoseMba This is becoming a new question. If you would accept this for the one posed here and create a new one for the one you are having now I would be happy to look into it. FYI `file_get_html` and `str_get_html` will return false under certain circumstances

Comment: I am using this method file_get_html($var);

Comment: What is `$var` and you will get `false` when `empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE` if $var is not empty the content is too big

Comment: Thanx for your great effort for ur help. But This the error I am getting  `Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in dom/simple_html_dom.php on line 687`

Answer (score -2):

You replace the whole array for each row so only the last URL will ever be scraped.

```
$result_links = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{ 
    array_push($result_links, $row);
}
```

Comment: The `[]` indicate it is an array, so what you say is not true.

Comment: @RST I know it is an array but the code doesn't append to the array it replaces the array.

Comment: `$array[] = "whatever";` would append `whatever` onto the end of `$array`. The `[]` means append to array exactly the same as `array_push`.

Comment: @JonathanBartlett - If you actually assign an array like this.
$result_links[] = "str" ; It actually appends to an existing array.